# Activeadmin form with a custom foreign key column name

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have two models `Person` and `Car` and I can't change the DB schema which has a foreign key column called `car` not `car_id` in the `Persons` table.

Till now it's ok because I used the following line in the `Person` model :

```
belongs_to :car,  class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'car'
```

And now for example if I tried `Person.last.car` it returns a `Car` object based on the `Car ID` in this column.

But the problem is with `Activeadmin` because if the user tried to edit a `Person` record it suppose to load the current `Car` and select it by default on the list but it doesn't.

My Form code :

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs 'Person Details' do
        ....
        ....
        f.input :car
        ....
        ....
    end
end
```

And also if I selected any car and clicked submit, I am facing this error `Car(#97670400) expected, got String(#19439720)`

Also I tried to make an alias for the column but with no luck

```
alias_attribute :ca_id, :car
```

I am using `Rails 5.0.2` and the latest `ActiveAdmin`.

Comment: Straight forward and simple answer would be changing the name to `car_id`, but as you insisted try changing `belongs_to :car,  class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'car'` to `belongs_to :person_car,  class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'car'`(just example). Not sure though.

Comment: @Pavan I want it to belongs_to `Car` which is another model, what do you mean by `person_car`.

Comment: I will explain it later. Did it worked?

Comment: @Pavan yes it worked

Comment: That's a typo? `:ca_id, :car`  Should have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Car(#97670400) expected, got String(#19439720)

As I said, the straight forward and simple answer would be changing the column name to `car_id`(*which is **recommended***) and using it in the form like `f.input :car_id` but as you insisted try providing a different(but meaningful) name to the *association*. Something like below

```
belongs_to :person_car, class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'car'
```

**Explanation:**

- *Naming Conflicts*

You should avoid *naming conflicts*. The `car`(*column name*) in `f.input :car` conflicts with the *association name* `car` in `belongs_to :car,  class_name: 'Car', foreign_key: 'car'` That is the reason for the error